# SQL Server trigger with based on two columns on a table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table `stockm` with plenty of columns, but my trigger is based only on two of them.

I want a trigger to send an email when the value in column `held_flag` is going to update or insert with `y` or `Y`, but to fire only, when in column `warehouse` the value is `KW`.

Let me know where I am wrong.

I mention no primary key on the table

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgStockHold]
ON [dbo].[stockm]
AFTER  UPDATE, INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @inserted_held_flag nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @inserted_rowstamp nvarchar(255)

    SELECT TOP 1 
        @inserted_held_flag = held_flag, 
        @inserted_rowstamp = rowstamp
    FROM 
        inserted 

    IF (@inserted_held_flag in ('Y','y'))
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                   FROM dbo.stockm 
                   WHERE rowstamp = @inserted_rowstamp AND warehouse = 'KW')
        BEGIN
            EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                        @profile_name = '', 
                        @recipients = '' , 
                        @body = '',
                        @subject = ' ' 
        END
END
```

Comment: What is the issue

Comment: Is the datatype correct

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statement that causes this trigger to fire inserts 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Your `SELECT TOP 1 ... FROM Inserted` will get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: The issue is:  I cannot run it and I need someone to help me if is possible to do a better one.

Answer (score 0):

So let's take a step backwards and think about this approach. First, a trigger operates within a transaction. That transaction might not be committed, meaing whatever rows were inserted are never actually saved permanently in the database. So the idea of sending an email from the trigger is a problematic action because that email might reference information that does not actually exist.

Next, transactions are supposed to be quick. You should not be executing logic that might take significant time. Sending an email usually doesn't require much time - but what happens when your email server is not working? Does your OLTP system simply stop working? Is that an acceptable risk in your system?

Lastly, a trigger operates on a statement-basis. If a statement affects 2000 rows, then 2000 rows will be present in the virtual inserted/deleted tables (depending on the action). To write a trigger correctly, your logic must be written to handle any number of rows - from zero (yes, zero!) to many. You assumed that a single row was affected - that is never a safe assumption. Because of that assumption, I can also guess that your testing does not cover a situation where multiple rows are actually affected. This is something you need to change - the sooner the better.

If you want suggestions for a better design, then you need to provide information about your goal and your schema. No one can really guess what your table/columns actually represent since they are not particularly meaningful names. Nor do your readers know the actual system you are modelling - so the business function cannot be deduced from your description.

And one last thing. If you intend to send an email using tsql, you will obiously need to provide correct information to the sp_send_dbmail procedure. If you don't know how to do that yet, then attempting to put it into a trigger is obviously not going to work either. Break your problem into parts that you can implement and test.